# display: none if date is expired

Tags: jquery, date

I'm trying to hide dates of concerts, after 4 weeks have passed, when the concert happened. After 1 day, it should turn red.

Here's what I found elsewhere:

```
$('#timeTable tr td').each(function () {
    var dtSt = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var dtAr = dtSt[0].split("/");
    var when = new Date(dtAr[1] + "/" + dtAr[0] + "/" + dtAr[2] + " " + dtSt[1]);
    console.log(when);    
    var now = Date.now();

    if (now - when > 2419200000) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('four_weeks');
    } else if (now - when > 86400000) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('one_day');
    } 
});
```

It works fine with tables, but i want it to work with the divs i got, so
I changed the `#timetable` parts in my structure:

```
$('.termin .termin_content h3').each(function () {
    if (now - when > 2419200000) {
        $(this).parent('h3').addClass('four_weeks');
    } else if (now - when > 86400000) {
        $(this).parent('h3').addClass('one_day');
    }
});
```

I guess this is not how things work. Would it even be possible to get rid of the time of day or is it needed to be calculated?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt8sf7gL/18/)

Comment: 1 thing:"`parent('h3')` only takes parent if it is an <h3>, element, you might want to use `closest()` instead, you can read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: @Seba i added a possible solution to your case scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the selector and later to mark the h3 tag, i did small changes in your code.

```
$('.termin h3').each(function () {
    var dtSt = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var dtAr = dtSt[0].split(".");
    var when = new Date(dtAr[1] + "/" + dtAr[0] + "/" + dtAr[2] + " " + dtSt[1]);
    console.log(when);    
    var now = Date.now();

    if (now - when > 2419200000) {
        $(this).addClass('four_weeks');
    } else if (now - when > 86400000) {
        $(this).addClass('one_day');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ktfvq9r/

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the time of day? And can I add the class to the whole div?

Comment: @Seba yes, actually in the code the time is not used, and to add the class to the div just add $(this).parent().addClass() and you will acc the class to the div with the class "termin_concert"

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!